# Bootstrap modal solo se muestra una vez como modal

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo en una aplicación ASP MVC, tengo la necesidad de mostrar una imagen en una ventana Modal utilizando bootstrap, la ventana modal sera llamada desde una celda de una tabla este es mi HTML para disparar el modal:

```
<td class="celda">
  <!--Aqui es donde mando a llamar al Popup-->
  @Html.Raw("<a id='btnPhoto' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/photo/" + item.MaterialId + "' id='" + item.MaterialId + "' title='Actualizar imagen del material'> <span class='fa fa-camera fa-lg'> </span></a>")

  @Html.Raw("<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>")
  @Html.Raw("<a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/details/" + item.MaterialId + "' id='" + item.MaterialId + "' title='Consultar Unidad de medida'> <span class='fa fa-search fa-lg'> </span></a>")
  @Html.Raw("<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>")
  @Html.Raw("<a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/edit/" + item.MaterialId + "' id='" + item.MaterialId + "' title='Editar Unidad de medida'> <span class='fa fa-pencil fa-lg'> </span></a>")
  @Html.Raw("<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>")
  @Html.Raw("<a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/delete/" + item.MaterialId + "' id='" + item.MaterialId + "' title='Eliminar Unidad de medida'> <span class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'> </span> </a>")
</td>
```

Este es el fragmento de HTMl donde se agrega la ventana modal:

```
<script src="~/Content/popup/popup.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/popup/popupimagen.js"></script>
<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div id='myModalContent'></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Este es el HTMl para la vista que debe de mostrarse como Modal:

```
        @model xxx.WebUi.Models.MaterialViewModel

        @{
            Layout = null;
        }

        <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>*@

                <link href="~/Content/popup/popupstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">

                    <h3 class="modal-title">
                        xxxx
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                    </h3>
                </div>


                <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Photo", "Materiales", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Styles.Render("~/Content/toastr")

                        <div class="form-horizontal">

                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MaterialId)
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            <div>
                                @if (Model.ImagenViewModel != null){
                                    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImagenViewModel.Contenido)" alt="imagen" style="width: 350px; height: 350px" />
                                }
                                else                        {
                                    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="~/Content/images/no-disponible.png" alt="imagen" style="width: 350px; height: 350px" />
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-2">
                                    <!-- image-preview-filename input [CUT FROM HERE]-->
                                    <div class="input-group image-preview">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control image-preview-filename" disabled="disabled"> <!-- don't give a name === doesn't send on POST/GET -->
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <!-- image-preview-clear button -->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger image-preview-clear" style="display: none;">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear
                                            </button>
                                            <!-- image-preview-input -->
                                            <div class="btn btn-info image-preview-input">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                                <span class="image-preview-input-title">Browse</span>
                                                <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="upload" /> <!-- rename it -->
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                    </div><!-- /input-group image-preview [TO HERE]-->
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <br>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar" />
                                    <input aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btncancel" type="button" value="Aceptar" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Aqui el script que utilizo para mostrar las vistas como popup:

```
    $('#btnPhoto').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnPhoto').attr('data-modal', '');
    $('#btnPhoto').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    //$('#btnCreateUser').attr('href', '#myModal');
    /*$('#myModalContent').load("/Usuario/CreatePopUp" + '/' + $('#dropDownList').val(), function () {*/
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            /*backdrop: 'static',*/
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        //bindFormSpecial(this);
        $('#btnPhoto').removeAttr('data-modal');
        $('#btnPhoto').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
    return false;
});


$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        contentType: this.enctype,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                //Refresh
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

El tema es que por alguna razón el **PopUp se abre únicamente una vez como modal** y es cuando se hace click en el primer registro de la tabla, es decir, si tengo 4 registros el popup se muestra como popup cuando hago click en el primer registro pero al hacer click en el segundo, tercero o ***cualquier otro deja de mostrarse como Popup y se muestra como una vista normal***.

¿Alguna idea de que es lo que pudiera estar ocurriendo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código generado? Lo más probable es que tengas ID's repetidos, entonces al abrir el modal sólo se rellena con los datos de la primera fila.

Comment: Adicionalemnte a lo que dice Alvaro, en el `success`, vuelves a preguntar si es `success`, para eso lo mejor es preguntar si el `result` tiene algo de data dentro.

Comment: Hola Alvaro Montoro, el modal solo muestra la imagen correspondiente al registro desde donde se hizo click y el Id oculto, es todo, lo extraño es que solo se muestre con un solo registro, el que tiene el Id 1 y el que aparece primero en la tabla, probé eliminando la información y creando registros diferentes y persiste el mismo comportamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación Wilfredo, tomo en consideración tus comentarios y corrijo el script.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entiendo lo que comentas, y corregiré esa parte, creo que no me he explicado bien, ya que lo que no hace el script es mostrar correctamente la ventana los datos si se muestran correctamente, solo con el primer registro se muestra la vista como modal con la imagen correspondiente, si clickeo sobre otro registro la ventana ya no se muestra modal sino como una vista normal aunque con la información correspondiente al registro clickeado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que recomendaria es no usar @Html.Raw() para generar la tabla

```
<td class="celda">
  <!--Aqui es donde mando a llamar al Popup-->
  <a id='btnPhoto' data-target='#myModal' style='color: #004881' href='/materiales/photo/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Actualizar imagen del material'> 
    <span class='fa fa-camera fa-lg'> </span>
  </a>

  <b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
  <a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/details/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Consultar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-search fa-lg'> </span>
  </a>

  <b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
  <a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/edit/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Editar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-pencil fa-lg'> </span>
  </a>

  <b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
  <a id='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/delete/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Eliminar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'> </span> 
  </a>
</td>
```

usa el `@` para unir los valores al html

Ademas no uses este selector `$('#btnPhoto')` dentro de una tabla, define una class y usalo de selector

```
<a id='btnPhoto' data-target='#myModal' class='photo' style='color: #004881' href='/materiales/photo/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Actualizar imagen del material'>
```

entonces el selector quedaria

```
$('.photo').click(function() {...
```

Comment: Hola Leandro: Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy haciendo los cambios y probando, me gustaría saber por que es que no recomiendas usar @Html.Raw, ¿existe alguna desventaja en particular?

Comment: seguro existen muchas formas de lograr el mismo objetivo, el tema es que no todas son correctas, si asp.net mvc te provee un sistema de marcado en donde puede intercalar codigo servidor con tags html porque hacerlo todo codigo servidor, la idea es dejar el html lo mas simple para poder modificarlo con un editor y solo colocar las partes variables alli donde se necesiten

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en esta línea:

```
$('#btnPhoto').click(function (e) {
```

Ahí es dónde mediante jQuery le especificas el comportamiento al anchor (enlace, vínculo) sobre "qué debe hacer cuándo hago click" (todo lo que está dentro de la función anónima dentro de la llamada al método click() ).

**¿Cuál es el problema?** Que el comportamiento de "invocar" a una modal se está haciendo a un selector que tal cómo está escrito invoca a un elemento con la id=btnPhoto (el símbolo # hace referencia al id)

**¿Y si agrego ese id al resto de los enlaces?** Seguirías teniendo un problema similar ya que el atributo id está pensado para ser usado en un y sólo un elemento. Si quieres que un comportamiento se comparta en distintos elementos deberías usar una clase (class).

**¿Y cómo quedaría usando una clase?** Supongamos que a la clase la llamamaos popUpLink (para reutilizar lo que tienes, entonces te quedaría:

```
<td class="celda">
<a class='popUpLink' id='btnPhoto' data-target='#myModal' style='color: #004881' href='/materiales/photo/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Actualizar imagen del material'> 
    <span class='fa fa-camera fa-lg'> </span>
</a>

<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<a class='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/details/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Consultar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-search fa-lg'> </span>
</a>

<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<a class='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/edit/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Editar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-pencil fa-lg'> </span>
</a>
<b style = 'color: #004881'>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<a class='popUpLink' data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style = 'color: #004881' href='/materiales/delete/@item.MaterialId' id='@item.MaterialId' title='Eliminar Unidad de medida'> 
    <span class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'> </span> 
</a>
</td>
```

Y en el script te quedaría algo así

```
$('.popUpLink').click(function (e) {
  $('.popUpLink').attr('data-modal', '');
  $('.popUpLink').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
  $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
      keyboard: true
    }, 'show');
      $('.popUpLink').removeAttr('data-modal');
      $('.popUpLink').removeAttr('data-toggle');
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: pero esto que comentas es la misma respuesta que di hace 2 hs, o hay algo diferente que no encuentro?